# No signal when cabling a female wall plate

Tags: ethernet

I'm cabling a new part of my home and I tried to create 2 ports on my wall. To summarize my installation (schema at the end), I have my internet access downstair. I installed a netgear switch upstairs to connect my equipements there. Then from this switch I connected 2 cables which are running inside the wall to my house other part. Both cables are arriving at the same place to create 2 ethernet port.

If I connect to my cable to this kind of connector shown on the image, and then I'm connecting my computer to the female port, my computer has no connection, and the ethernet port is not event flashing.

Note: When cabling this connector I invert green and orange to correspond to the other end of my cable which is using T568A. However I did try T568B to be sure it wasn't the problem.

[image]

However If I use a male connector instead of the female one, and I plug it directly in my computer it works. I'm currently writing from the wifi provided by a router connected to this male connector.

I even tried to reproduce the wall cable with another cable running from my computer, to a female ethernet port as shown, itself connected to a switch, connected to the internet access modem. And it also worked fine. I did it to be certain I was clipping the right ethernet wire into the right socket.

So I have no clue at the moment why it is not working. I connected my cable to the female port several time this morning being carefull about how I connect it.

Here is a schema of what I tried if it can help. I ordered an ethernet tester to be even more certain I didn't screw up while connecting something.

[image: Connection schema]

Schema notes :

- A and B at the beginning of the cable are for the connection used (T568A/B)
- The cable number indicates which cable i used again
- The switch used in all 3 tests is the same

Edit to show how I wired a jack to test if I'm wiring it correctly :

[image]

**The solution :
The tester I ordered finally arrived, and it showed me my mistake. The plug on my cable 2 on my schema was in the wrong order (8->1 instead of 1->8). And instead of starting fresh I reproduced my error each time I created a new plug**

Comment: *I am not sure if you have altered cables or their ends, my comment assumes you have*. Have you tested all of the switches with Ethernet cables that are know to be good, ( factory ones you have not altered ) And if they all work the problem is the way you have altered or wired the in-wall cables. ( or the connector in the photo )

Comment: How are you attaching this jack/female connector? Do you have a proper punchdown tool, and experience using it? How are you attaching the plug/male connector? Have you tried a different jack in case this particular jack is damaged/defective?

Comment: @AlaskaMan the switch (singular, it's the same in all 3 tests) works fine. All my equipments plugged in upstairs works well. Moreover if my in-wall finishes with a male connector it works well. So I clearly must be messing up my female connection but cannot see how

Comment: @Ecnerwal no punchdown tool yet I just found out few days ago it is better with one. But to test if I wired the jack correctly, I did it manually with a small screw driver, and stripping the wire to be certain it makes contact. And the cable shown on my picture in my edit is working well as an extension (plug at one side, jack on the other). So my wiring seems correct

Comment: Gag me with a pitchfork. No wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: It was only for test purpose, and it proves it works on one random cable. But still does not work on my in-wall cable. Now for sure I won't do it like that when I get my punchdown tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never strip wires like that for a jack. It is very easy to short them together inside when you close the jack.

You also should have a cable tester that tests every wire individually. The best one I've ever used costs less than $10 (US). It has a series of lights 8 lights and tests each wire one at a time to make sure the connection is good. If you test your cables, you will see exactly what is wrong with them.

As noted in the comments, you must have a punchdown tool or use "toolless" jacks. This kind of jack is designed to crimp the wires into the terminals using pressure from closing the cover. I use these all the time - they cost only a few cents more, and they are much easier.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to make sure your jacks can do full speed (gigabit), keep the twists in the pairs as close as you can to the terminals. There should be no more than half an inch untwisted.

Comment: [This](https://www.microcenter.com/product/486708/inland-network-cable-tester) is the network cable tester I use. It is actually significantly better than some models that cost 5 times as much. (Of course there are real "pro" tools that cost hundreds or thousands of dollars that have more features, but this is the tool I need 99% of the time.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. As i said stripping wire like that was only for test purpose, because after lot of testing I even came to doubt the toolless jack was crimping the wires correctly.

Tester is on the way, as for the punchdown tool. Will get to bottom of the story soon I hope.

Comment: The tester has finally arrived and I facepalmed myself several time seeing that I created the cable 2 plug 8->1 instead of 1->8. And I wasn't finding my mistake because each time I created a new plug on cable 2 to be certain it still worked I used the old plug I just cut instead of starting fresh from an official color schema... I was too lazy